# Parse values out of paramaterized strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Say I have a string, such as:

```
var map = "/directory/:id/thumbnails/:size";
```

And I want to use that to map against another string (essentially, the same thing that Rails uses to define Routes), such as:

```
var str = "/directory/10/thumbnails/large";
```

I would like to "compare" the two strings, and return a Key-Value Pair or JSON Object that represents the parts of `str` that map to `map`, which in my example above, would look like:

```
obj = {
    'id'   : '10',
    'size' : 'large'
}
```

Would this be a good fit for JavaScript Regex?  Can anyone help me?

Comment: any good reason to be doing that with javascript instead of a server-side language?

Comment: I'm not actually using it for routing, that was just the most convenient example, since it's what everyone is likely familiar with.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can use a regexp to convert the map into a regexp, and then use that regexp to parse the string in question.

Comment: @Jason:  Could you point me to a JS example of that?

Comment: [Every time you say "JSON object," a ninja cuts off a baby animal's head.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) Please think of the cute widdle aminals, and use the right terminology.

Comment: @Mike Trpcic didn't thought about anything in specific, just asked the reasons behind it. It's possible alright, specially if the patter is always the same ... is it?

Comment: @Yoda:  The pattern can change, but should _usually_ be something akin to a filepath/url.

Comment: @Mike Trpcic, in that case, @Darko Z 's answer should be enougth for you to work with, no need for regex at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it easier to just write the code for this than to explain :)

```
var map = "/directory/:id/thumbnails/:size";
var str = "/directory/10/thumbnails/large";

var obj = {};

var mapArr = map.split('/');
var strArr = str.split('/');

if (mapArr.length != strArr.length) return false;

for (var i = 0; i < mapArr.length; i++)
{
    var m = mapArr[i];
    var s = strArr[i];

    if (m.indexOf(":") != 0) continue;

    m = m.substring(1);    
    obj[m] = s;
    document.write(m + " = ");
    document.write(obj[m]);
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

You can also see it in action here => http://jsfiddle.net/5qFkb/

Do ask if you have any questions, but the code should be self-explanatory. Also be aware that there is no usual null checking and stuff I'd usually put in - this is just meant as a quick and dirty proof of concept.

Oh and in case it wasn't clear from my answer; no, I wouldn't use regex, because then I'd have two problems instead of one.